# How to declare and call a model method navigating through relations in django?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-templates

I Have 3 models

```
class Room(models.Model):

    house = models.ForeignKey('Property', related_name='rooms')
    beds = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)

class Property(models.Model):

......

    def free_places():
        places = 0
        for r in self.rooms:
            x = r.beds - ((r.tenant).size())
            places = places + x
        return places


class Profile(model.Models):

    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, blank=True, null=True, related_name='tenant')
```

First of all I would like to know if free_places method should be: free_places(self) or free_places(). I think it has some errors too but I don't know how to test it, so here it's the question how can I call the method? and is it correct the function?
I want to call it from a django template.

To try it from "./manage.py shell" what do I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be free_places(self):

You can define the method as a property and then call that from the template:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-methods

Last example in that code block

```
def _free_places(self):
    places = 0
    for r in self.rooms:
        x = r.beds - ((r.tenant).size())
        places = places + x
    return places
free_places = property(_free_places)
```

Comment: Still not working, but it's because of the function itself. I tried your suggestion with a return 0 and in that case works fine. Any idea of what's wrong with the method?

Comment: @ConradKurtz Yes. Sorry. Should have answered that, too. From what I am aware, Size is neither a built in Python method or a Django queryset method. If I've interpreted your intentions correctly, it should be: r.beds - (len(r.tenant.all())) I would recommend changing the related name on the profile foreign key to room to 'tenants', however, as that describes the relationship more accurately. In this configuration, a room can have many profiles.